# checkmate w/ NA elements

Tags: r, assert

I'd like to use the [checkmate](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=checkmate) package in R to determine if all elements in a character vector either (a) are NA or (b) conform to the regex pattern.  (In this specific case, an element may contain only digits.)

The call below returns "Assertion on 'x' failed: Must comply to pattern '^\d{2,3}$'", even with the `any.missing` parameter set to TRUE.  Is there a natural & concise way to test this w/ checkmate?  Is the `any.missing` parameter essentially ignored if a regex pattern is used?

```
x <- c("11", "22", "333", NA_character_)
pattern <- "^\\d{2,3}$"

checkmate::assert_character(x,  pattern=pattern, any.missing=TRUE)
```

For reference, a similar expression using [testit](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=testit) is

```
testit::assert(
  "Any existing elements must be missing or only digits",
  all(is.na(x) | grepl(pattern, x)
)
```

Comment: This is reproducible and counter to the docs. I suggest you raise it as [an issue on github](https://github.com/mllg/checkmate/issues). In the interim, I suggest you revert to the `testit` variant, or even `stopifnot(grepl(pattern, x) | is.na(x))`.

Comment: another workaround until it is fixed would be `checkmate::assert_character(x[!is.na(x)], pattern = pattern, any.missing = TRUE)`  (technically, the `any.missing` argument is redundant, but could be preserved so that `[!is.na(x)]` could be removed at a later date)

Comment: It looks like the problem is at https://github.com/mllg/checkmate/blob/master/R/checkCharacter.R#L29 . The `checkCharacterPattern` subroutine doesn't take the `any.missing` or `all.missing` arguments into consideration. Missing values always return `FALSE` from `grepl`.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Submitted as https://github.com/mllg/checkmate/issues/106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following https://github.com/mllg/checkmate/issues/106, the `any.missing` parameter is no longer ignored when a regex pattern is supplied.